# react native update to 0.31.0 RCTNetwork error

Tags: react-native

I update react-native to 0.31.0, redbox as follow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXYmj.png)

After remove the `fetch` method in my project, the error box disappeared too.

And this error only happens in iOS program.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's just a bug. Downgrade to 0.30